# onClick update the rows in table like structure REact JS and JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am developing a react JS component with JSX coding structure that gets a JSON array of data from api. The component is a table like structure and has two arrows at the top and bottom. I want to achieve a functionality where on click of top arrow the table rows should be updated with new set of data in rows and vice-versa happens on click of down arrow. Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to do some sort of table paging. You can do this by storing the current page on the state of your control, and on the onClick handler:

- make the call to the server API to retrieve the data for the next/previous page if you are paging and sorting on the server, then update the state with the retrieved data
- or calculate and update the state with whichever rows you want to display if you already have all rows in memory but are showing a small set of them

Comment: currently I am getting all the data from server I am able to retrieve a data but what I trying to do is on click of up arrow 4 set of rows should shift up and next set of rows with new data should show up and same with the down arrow.

Comment: Right. On your onClick method you should be setting the state (ie, adding those rows you want to display, and removing those you want to hide). But only from the state, not from the actual place in memory where you store the data retrieved. So, let's say you want to display 10 rows out of 80, then you make a copy of those 10 into the state. When the user clicks the down arrow you change those 10 by removing the top 4 and adding the bottom 4.